# Nextjs Image component complaining that the host is not added to config, but it is

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have a weeeeeeird issue with Nextjs, I have it connected to a cms (storyblok) and all images that I use come from that place. All images work just fine, but now I added a few new ones and I keep getting the error that the host is not configured, but it is!

Error:

```
Error: Invalid src prop (https://a.storyblok.com/f/130657/88x88/f37f10e611/giantstitanslogo.png) on `next/image`, hostname "a.storyblok.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

Component, logoImg.filename is the src url:

```
      <Image
        src={logoImg.filename}
        alt={logoImg.alt}
        width={logoImgDimensions.width}
        height={logoImgDimensions.height}
        layout="responsive"
      />
```

And the config:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["a.storyblok.com"],
  },
  experimental: { esmExternals: true },
};
```

Also if I do the following:

1. Comment out the Image component and save
2. Refresh
3. Error is gone page loads
4. Now uncomment the Image component and save (without refresh)
5. The images show up just fine!
6. Refresh -> error again

Comment: ["a.storyblok.com"] try  ['a.storyblok.com']

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and restarting the dev server?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, no difference

Comment: @illiachill I tried, no change, also like I mentioned, I have probably 20 images on the page coming from a.storyblok.com all work just fine except these 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidently found the answer here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18311#discussioncomment-113194

For whatever reason my `Image` component was imported from `"next/Image"` not `"next/image"` image with small "`i`", once I changed the import to "next/image" it worked just fine.